# How to remove name in WooCommerce customer emails

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

for some reason the emails being sent to customers after they create a WooCommerce account displays a random name (see attached).

[WooCommerce username error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ENXM.jpg)

I think because users can create an account with just an email address? But anyway - I want to just remove the Hi xxxx from all email communication from the customer. How do I do this? I am looking at the email templates but can't see how this code is generated?

Comment: Could you post your email template code?

Comment: or you can use this plugin to customize default woo commerce email template https://wordpress.org/plugins/kadence-woocommerce-email-designer/

Comment: This was a plugin conflict and is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the name from email communication, you need to copy the email template file in your theme directory (e.g - customer-processing-order.php) on this find the below code:

```
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
```

And replace with the below mentioned code:

```
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
```

Same thing you can do for following Woocommerce email template files:

```
customer-completed-order.php
customer-completed-order.php
customer-invoice.php
customer-note.php
customer-on-hold-order.php
customer-processing-order.php
customer-refunded-order.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - yes that solved the issue. The problem occurred because of a plugin conflict with a translation plugin. Thanks for the response to the question.